# How can I run Minecraft in the background?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway I can run Minecraft in the background so I can harvest items from my automated mob grinder while doing other activities, other than by setting up a server for myself? If I just minimise the game, it automatically pauses itself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open up your inventory (or the crafting window or furnace window) and then minimize the game.

Comment: I wonder if you can do CTRL+ALT+DEL and then when Minecraft loses focus just downsize it.

Comment: Hitting 't' to bring up chat works too, and you can still see what's going on.

Comment: If you're in multiplayer, the server will run regardless of what you do client-side.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> allows you to minimize the game without it becoming suspended. There are other <kbd>F3</kbd> debug commands, too.